# setting the backgroundTint in an app widget

Tags: java, android, background-color, android-appwidget

I want to change the background color of a button in my app widget.
Because I want to keep the shape of the normal android button I thought about backgroundTint. I have to set the color programmatically in the onUpdate method of my widget class.

I tried:

```java
views.setInt(buttonId, "setBackgroundColor", Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

-> changes the button shape as well

```java
views.setInt(buttonId, "setBackgroundTint", Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
views.setInt(buttonId, "setTint", Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
views.setInt(buttonId, "setColorFilter", Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

-> widget cannot be displayed (no error code in logcat)

```java
views.setInt(buttonId, "setBackgroundTintList", colorStateList );
```

-> expects a ColorStateList not int...

Do you know a solution or a simple alternative?

Edit:
Some more code:

AppWidget.java:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.app_widget);

            views.setCharSequence(buttonId, "setText", "TEXT");
            //views.setInt(buttonId, "setColorFilter", Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

        }
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

app_widget.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llWidget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Color"
        android:text="string" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the problem with `someView.setBackgroundTint(...)` ?

Comment: Its impossible because there is no direct access to the button from the AppWidgetProvider.

Comment: You're right, I haven't used this in a *very long time* (I didn't think people still used these) :) Anyway, you may want to post your theme/style too, because afaicr, the whole thing pick values from your theme.

Comment: I haven't changed the theme, it's still default. I think changing the theme of the widget is impossible during runtime as well. Maybe if i switch the whole layout xml. But thats not a very "good" way ofc.

Comment: At this point, I think you may want to share more code though. How are you using the thing and what not. Because even tho I cannot remember very well how this was done, I would have more chances of spotting something if I can read it :)

Comment: Ok sorry, i edited my post with some the widget class and xml ;-)

Comment: Create a custom background drawable resource (e.g., some `ShapeDrawables` in a `StateListDrawable`, for the different states). Then, reference that background in your layout resource.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing something like @CommonsWare suggested. I created a drawable for each color. Depending on the state (pressed/not pressed/...) it sets a .png image. I took the images of the standard android buttons and changed their color manually. They are located somewhere in the ...\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\data\res folder.

Finally i set the drawable as background using the following code:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.app_widget);
views.setInt(R.id.button, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.btn_color);
```